# Where is kernel.img?

Tags: boot, noobs

I have installed the NOOBS files [per instructions](http://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/quick-start-guide-v2_1.pdf). When I start up, I get stuck on the coloured screen. The [troubleshooting guide](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Coloured_splash_screen) indicates this is due to missing/corrupt kernel.img. Where should I get this file from - it is not part of the NOOBS download (unless I'm missing something stupid).

Comment: Question. Is the MD5 of the NOOBS zip good? Sometimes a download hiccups and the file gets slightly corrupted. Not enough to cause a problem when you unzip the file, but enough to cause a problem like what you're saying.

Answer (score 1):

It is part of the NOOBS download - assuming you're using Raspbian or one of the other OSs in the NOOBS package.  The installation process will place it in /boot/kernel.img.

I would try the installation again, either on a fresh SD card or reformat the one that failed.  It sounds as though it simply corrupted in some way.

Check that the card is large enough to hold it - minimum of 4Gb and I wouldn't use anything slower than a class 4.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to add "boot_delay=1" to the config.txt file.

This is also suggested on the troubleshooting guide, but the first time I did this, I created a file called config.txt.txt